# SQL Delete all results except Top and Bottom

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have a system that stores data, but the only relevant data for us is the first bit of data for the day, and the latest bit of data for the day.

We want to run an SQL Agent job every 20 mins to clear out everything that isn't the first or latest for the day, but I don't know how to delete everything except top and bottom.

I know how to do it on just one or the other, but not both at the same time.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Start by writing a query which selects the data you are interested in, then your delete can reference `not in` said query.

Comment: Provide sample data and what you have tried. It will make things more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a deletable CTE, something like:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(ts_col AS date) ORDER BY ts_col) rn_start,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(ts_col AS date) ORDER BY ts_col DESC) rn_end
    FROM yourTable
)

DELETE
FROM cte
WHERE rn_start <> 1 AND rn_end <> 1;
```

Here, I assume that you have some timestamp column called `ts_col`.  The above logic partitions row number based on the *date* itself (not the timestamp), then identifies the first and last records for each date, sparing those records from deletion.

Comment: Thank you so much Tim.  That's functioning exactly how I want it to.  Thanks for the great solution even though the level of detail included was so sparse!

Answer (score 0):

You have not given us any query so I could only give you an example on how you could do it.

See below example.

```
Delete From User
where Id not in (select top 5 Id from User)
and Id not in (select top 5 Id from User order by desc Id)
```

Now you will delete everything except for the top 5 and the bottom 5 of the user table.

Comment: You probably need an `order by` in your first sub-query, else it will be random.

Comment: Nope its already gets the data from top to bottom so there is no need.

Comment: Thats not correct - any query in T-SQL **without** an `order by` does not guarantee the order of the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS(
SELECT * from sys.tables where name ='DeleteTopandBottonRow'
)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE DeleteTopandBottonRow
END
GO

CREATE TABLE DeleteTopandBottonRow
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Data UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    CreatedDate DATETIME
)
GO
INSERT INTO DeleteTopandBottonRow
(
    Data,
    CreatedDate
)
SELECT NEWID() AS DATA  ,GETDATE() AS CreatedDate
GO 50


DELETE 
FROM    DeleteTopandBottonRow
WHERE   CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) = CAST(CreatedDate AS DATE)
        AND DeleteTopandBottonRow.ID
        NOT IN
        (
            SELECT  MIN(DeleteTopandBottonRow.ID) 
            FROM    DeleteTopandBottonRow
            WHERE   CAST(Getdate() AS DATE) = CAST(CreatedDate AS DATE)

            UNION ALL 

            SELECT  MAX(DeleteTopandBottonRow.ID) 
            FROM    DeleteTopandBottonRow
            WHERE   CAST(Getdate() AS DATE) = CAST(CreatedDate AS DATE)
        )
GO

SELECT * FROM  DeleteTopandBottonRow
GO
```

Comment: Please add some description in addition to the code.